# Find an undecidable language that is mapping-reducible to its complement

Tags: computability, reductions

As the title suggests. Also, such a language must satisfy that neither it nor its complement are semi-decidable. I already know that $All_{TM}, EQ_{TM}, T$ (that is the set of all deciders) satisfy this property. But I tried reducing these to their complements directly, and via some sort of intermediate language, but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following construction. Given a language $L$, use
$$ \{0x : x \notin L\} \cup \{1x : x \in L\}. $$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you perhaps expand a little bit on this?

Comment: Consider all possible words. Prefix those which belong to $L$ by $1$, those that don't by $0$. This may be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Another more advanced answer is to look at a complete problem from a class that is closed under complement. For example, take the [arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) which is closed under complements. Now consider a complete problem for it like:

> Given: a sentence in the language of [first-order arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_arithmetic),
>   Question: is the sentence true (in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$)?

It is easy that one can reduce this to its complement by negating the sentence.

This works generally for any class that is closed under completion and has a complete problem (w.r.t. [many-one reductions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction)).